# Jquery ajax call within Phonegap to RESTful API

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, rest, cordova

I'm trying to make a RESTful api call from the android emulator (using android 2.2).  On my server for the login request I'm setting the [cors header](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

This exact code works fine from Firefox 4 and Chrome 10 and I was led to believe the android browser resolves this header from version [2.1 up](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors).

```
usr = $("#email").val();
pwd = $("#password").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://myremoteserver/login",
    data: {"username": escape(usr), "password": escape(pwd)},
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("Success: " + response);
      if (response.result == "success") {
        //doStuff
      }
      else {
        console.log("Success Error: " + response);
        $("#error").html(response);
      }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      console.log("Error status " + status);
      console.log("Error request status text: " + request.statusText);
      console.log("Error request status: " + request.status);
      console.log("Error request response text: " + request.responseText);
      console.log("Error response header: " + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
      $("#error").html(status);
    }

});
```

The server never receives the request and the status code is 0 which I've read can mean a cross scripting error.  But, as I've said, it works fine in modern browsers.

These are the pertinent logs I see in the LogCat

```
03-29 20:30:46.935: DEBUG/PhoneGapLog(277): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 36 : Error status error
03-29 20:30:46.935: INFO/Web Console(277): Error status error at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:36
03-29 20:30:46.954: DEBUG/PhoneGapLog(277): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 37 : Error request status text: error
03-29 20:30:46.954: INFO/Web Console(277): Error request status text: error at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:37
03-29 20:30:46.985: DEBUG/PhoneGapLog(277): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 38 : Error request status: 0
03-29 20:30:46.985: INFO/Web Console(277): Error request status: 0 at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:38
03-29 20:30:47.003: DEBUG/PhoneGapLog(277): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 39 : Error request response text: 
03-29 20:30:47.003: INFO/Web Console(277): Error request response text:  at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:39
03-29 20:30:47.034: DEBUG/PhoneGapLog(277): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 40 : Error response header: 
03-29 20:30:47.034: INFO/Web Console(277): Error response header:  at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:40
03-29 20:33:38.704: DEBUG/SntpClient(65): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

As you can see there isn't a whole lot there... makes it a pain to try to debug anything.

Edit:
AndroidManifest.xml permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Can you please output error.message instead of error?

Comment: @knoguchi console.log(error.message); gives me: undefined

Comment: oh yeh I mixed it up with local storage. Have you set internet access permission in android manifest xml file?

Comment: @knoguchi yea it does - I've edited my post to include the permissions section of my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: If the server hasn't got the request at all, the status code 0 possibly indicating that there is some problem with firewall. Have you try turning it off?

Comment: @knoguchi I'm running the emulator from the same machine I was doing the browser tests so I wouldn't think that would be a problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue.. I have tried both 'POST' and 'GET' in the types, I have also tried datatype: 'json' and nothing... I can echo the URL to the phone's screen and click on it and the request works, so I know the URL is good.. this is just frustrating. I am using PhoneGap 0.9.4 and Jquery 1.5.2 (I also tried 1.4.4 from another forums recommendation and it still didn't work.)

Comment: @Wrenbjor I had to do the same (downgrade to 1.4.4), apparently the $.ajax rewrite broke some things dealing with file://.  My initial problem was that my emulator wasn't connecting to the internet at all though.  Make sure all the js is loaded on the index.html page.  JS defined on other pages won't work (see known limitations at http://jquerymobile.com/test/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the android emulator not being able to connect to the internet.  It was fixed by adding `-dns-server X.X.X.X` (where X.X.X.X is my dns server) to the "Default emulator options" in the Android preferences in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are calling RESTful API for login service, I think you need to specify the ajax type to be POST method because it is GET method in default. i.e.,

$.ajax({ type: 'POST', ... });

I think that is why server is not returning any response.

If this does not fix your problem, could you tell me if you can successfully access other web services (anything on the web) from the application?

Comment: I'll preface this by saying Phonegap may just not be the right tool for my needs, but I have several problems with this.  I'm trying to get information (is this a valid login?) therefor it should be a GET request.  Second, the GET request actually works in FF4 and Chrome 10.  It may be that phonegap needs to provide a plugin to access the phones network capabilities in order to do this "correctly".

Comment: Hmmm I actually made phonegap app that sends request with ajax and there is no problem with it. You probably want to see if ajax requests work with different server like www.google.com (If you still want to use phonegap ofcourse :) ).

Comment: Perhaps the problem lies with the emulator.  I'll try a real phone when I remember to bring my USB adapter in to work.